# disable "show base" item in Modelsim for automation

Tags: modelsim

I have trying to write a do do file for automation.
I want to disable the "show base " item in waveform.
So what is the command ?

Comment: Try to put "radix noshowbase" in your simulation script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options (from [ModelSim Command Reference Manual](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/134097-modelsim-command-reference-manual-v10-3a)):

1. Add `radix hexadecimal` to your script (the default is `radix hexadecimal -showbase`)
2. Use `DefaultRadix` directive in your modelsim.ini
3. Choose Simulate > Runtime Options from the main menu, click the Defaults tab, uncheck the `Showbase` in Default RadixFlags panel

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-documented option of the `add wave` command to set the show base state (in addition to the documented `-showbase` option).
To disable it add **`-radixshowbase 0`** to the command.

Such things are discoverable by configuring a wave window, saving it (File/Save Format) to a file and then taking a look.